# Installing Chrome on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash

I am trying to install Chrome on my system but instead of installing it says 'reinstall' and never actually opens or loads. This is also the case when I try to install Flash Player - I can see the file in software centre but it doesn't actually install.

Sorry I am very new to Ubuntu.

My laptop has the following processor:

```
Intel® Pentium(R) M processor 1.70GHz 
748.3mb RAM
```

Thank you

Comment: Would [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_%28web_browser%29) suit you? If yes you can try to install it from the Software Centre as a simpler solution.

Answer (score 11):

To install google chrome Either download from PPA or using `.deb`

#### PPA

Using terminal. run those commands, you can open termianl by searching from dash or keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

#### using .deb

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg –i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Since this is a "very new" user, you might wish to enrich your answer explaining where and how to run these commands.

Comment: +1 here.  Note that you will want to add "[arch=amd64]" to the repository since google is only supporting 64bit chrome now. Without this extra bit, you will receive errors during the update process. It should look like the following:  "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main"

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to install it? I recommend running this command from a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and totally remove chrome using the following code

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove google-chrome-stable
```

You also need to delete or rename `/home/your_name/.config/google-chrome` (`.config` is hidden. You'll need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see it)

then finally run this in your terminal to install chrome, as found on the following [link](http://howtoubuntu.org/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr)

```
if [[ $(getconf LONG_BIT) = "64" ]]
then
    echo "64bit Detected" &&
    echo "Installing Google Chrome" &&
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb &&
    sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb &&
    rm -f google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
else
    echo "32bit Detected" &&
    echo "Installing Google Chrome" &&
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb &&
    sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb &&
    rm -f google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
fi
```

Comment: Rather than pointing to an external link, please copy-paste the relevant portion in your answer so that the info is safe even if that site is offline..(don't forget to give credit to them though)

Answer (score 0):

GO to google chrome site and download, save file in downloads. Do not let it open in software center yet. GO to downloads and right click on the chrome downloaded file and select let program run as install (Executable) . Close that and double click the file, should open software center and install.

Comment: What will this do?